# typescript singleton design pattern : this is undefined

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, singleton, nativescript

I've implemented the singleton pattern in a typescript ( 2.1.6 ) class as follows:

```
export class NotificationsViewModel {
    private _myService: NotificationService;
    private _myArray: [];
    private static _instance: NotificationsViewModel;
    private constructor() {
        this._myService = new NotificationService();
        this._myArray = [];
        NotificationsViewModel._instance = this;
    }
    public static getInstance(): NotificationsViewModel {
        if (!this._instance) {
            this._instance = new NotificationsViewModel();
        }
        return this._instance;
    }
    public startListening() {
        return this._myService.addUserNotificationChildListener(this.handleNotifications);
    }
    private handleNotifications(notification: Models.NotificationItem) {
        this._myArray.push(notification);// this line breaks
    }
}
```

Interestingly **the `handleNotifications` method fails with error `cannot read property _myArray of undefined`**. Basically it's saying that `this` - which equals `instance` - is not instantied (correct ? ). 
What I don't understand is how this is possible, as `this._myService` is used without any problem.

Am I implementing the pattern in the wrong way? Why is this happening?

**EDIT**
Here is the code that calls the class :

```
    notificationsViewModel = NotificationsViewModel.getInstance(mainUser);
    notificationsViewModel.initialize().then(() => {
        notificationsViewModel.startListening();
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.dump(error);
    });
```

I've not included the `initialize` method in the snippet above, but it returns a promise.

Comment: Can you please add the code which uses this class/instance?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Sure, coming up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem here is the classic "wrong `this` context", because you are passing a reference to the `handleNotifications` method which isn't bound to the instance.

It should be:

```
public startListening() {
    return this._myService.addUserNotificationChildListener(this.handleNotifications.bind(this));
}
```

Or:

```
public startListening() {
    return this._myService.addUserNotificationChildListener(notification => this.handleNotifications(notification));
}
```

Also, there's no need to create an instance in your constructor:

```
private constructor() {
    this._myService = new NotificationService();
    this._myArray = [];
    NotificationsViewModel._instance = this; // this is redundant
}
```

Comment: Ohh I see! This fixed the problem....but there's something I don't understand : if the `handleNotifications` method is not bound to the instance, why am I getting an error only when accessing the array inside the method? For example, if I were to `console.log("foo")¡ in `handleNotifications` I wouldn't get errors..

Comment: You are passing a reference to the function which is valid reference so it can be invoked. **But** when using `this` inside the function will reference a different object than the instance of `NotificationsViewModel`

Comment: Ohh now I got it!! Sorry to bother you but I find this really interesting, which object is `this` bound to inside the `handleNotifications` method?

Comment: That varries..  Probably `window` if it's in the browser, but it's easy to find out. Just put `console.log(this)` and see what you get

Comment: This mess a lot of binding. thanks for the solution.